# Bootstrap 4.3 card-deck doesn't set the column count

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4.3 and custom Bootstrap SCSS imports. I try to setup my Bootstrap `card-deck` for my custom theme. But it doesn't set the `$card-columns-count` correctly (see screenshot). It should set it to 3 columns?

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong? I checked everything and can't find some wrong markup or missing code or something.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="js-view-dom-id-782ad9c1f67057f3ddbbae335925382482f61ffa0bbdb300906427454d9c43d7 card-deck">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
          <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
          <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
            Base Jump Kasteel
          <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
          <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
          <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
            Base Jump Kasteel
          <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
          <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
          <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
            Base Jump Kasteel
          <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
          <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
          <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
            Base Jump Kasteel
          <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
          <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
          <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
            Base Jump Kasteel
          <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
          <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
          <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
            Base Jump Kasteel
          <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to override a few CSS as I override refer below snippet for your solution...

```
@media (min-width: 576px){
  .card-deck {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .card-deck .card {
    flex: 32% 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/njbxeqch/10/)

Comment: But why is extra code necessary? Bootstrap 4.3 `card-deck` should divide the columns in 3 columns by default isn't it? Provided by the `$card-columns-count` `variable.